# How to add/update data at nested level in existing Index using Logstash mutate plugin

Tags: logstash

I have multiple logstash pipelines set up on server that feeds data in Index. Every pipelines adds bunch of fields at the first level of Index along with their nested level.

I already have kpi1 and kpi2 values inside Metrics => data with Metrics being nested array. And I have a requirement to add a new pipeline that will feed the value of kpi3. Here is my filter section in the new pipeline that I created:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            event.set('kpi3', event.get('scoreinvitation'))            
            "
    }
     mutate {
        # Rename the properties according to the document schema.
        rename => {"kpi3" => "[metrics][data][kpi3]"}
     }
   
}
```

It overwrites the Metrics section ( may be  because it is an array??). Here is my mapping :

```
 "metrics" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "data" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "kpi1" : {
                   ....
                   }
                  }
                }
                "name" : {
                 "type" : "text",
                 ....
                 }
               }
            }
```

How can I keep the existing fields (and values) and still add the new fields inside Metrics => Data ? Any help is appeciated.

Comment: Please share the possible value of kpi3

Answer (score 0):

The Logstash pipeline looks good, however your mapping doesn't make much sense to me if I'm understanding your requirement correctly.

The `metrics` property doesn't have to be of type `nested`. In fact, the metrics property is just a json namespace that contains sub-fields / -objects.

Try the following mapping instead

```
"metrics": {
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "properties": {
        "kpi1": {
          # if you want to assign a value to the kpi1 field, it must have a type
        }
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ```KPI1``` has a type text.  I can't change the mapping as it is already in use with multiple pipelines feeding data to it for a long time. And there is a reason for ```Metrics``` property to be nested. ```Data``` property is associated with ```Name```. So ```Metrics``` can have multiple ```Data``` with unique ```Name```.